# How to Autofit table row height?

Tags: vba, ms-word, row, height

Using MS Word VBA. I already have a nice macro that autofits all table widths to the window size (margin to margin).

I'm looking to do something similar to autofit all of the table row heights to display all of the text in each row. Currently, the table rows only display one line, and then the text wraps below and is not visible.

Any help is appreciated. Code is below:

```vb
Sub ResizeAllTables()
    Dim oTbl As Table

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        oTbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    Next oTbl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [Row.HeightRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.row.heightrule) property. Specifically, you will want it to be set to [wdRowHeightAuto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrowheightrule) which is

> The row height is adjusted to accommodate the tallest value in the row.

So using your example I would imagine it would look something like this

```vb
Sub ResizeAllTables()
    Dim oTbl As Table

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        oTbl.Rows.HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto
    Next oTbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a similar property for autofitting table column width?